# How to update a Python instance attribute

Tags: python, oop, web-scraping, initialization

I am having an issue with updating an instance attribute.

First, I want to initialize an attribute to `None`

Secondly, I want to run a function. If the function is successful, I want to update the attribute. If the function is unsuccessful, return None.

I have tried using the `@property` and `@contents.setter` decorators, but seem to be getting something wrong. To limit confusion, I have removed the decorators.

```
class OlympicAthlete:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.url = f'https://www.olympic.org/{name}'
        self.contents = None

    def contents(self):
        r = requests.get(self.url)
        if r.status_code != 200:
            print(f'Your get request was unsuccessful with a {r.status_code} error code')
            return None
        self.contents = r.text


phelps = OlympicAthlete('michael-phelps')
phelps.contents()
print(phelps.contents)
```

After calling `print(phelps.contents)`, I was expecting see the html text for that page.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you initialize the `OlympicAthlete` class, the method `contents` gets overwritten by None. That is why calling the `contents` method results in an error, as NoneType object is not callable.
Therefore you need to start by naming the `contents` attribute differently from the method as one overwrites the other.

I would suggest something along the lines of

```py
class OlympicAthlete:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.url = f'https://www.olympic.org/{name}'
        self.contents = None

    def get_content(self):
        r = requests.get(self.url)
        if r.status_code != 200:
            print(f'Your get request was unsuccessful with a {r.status_code} error code')
            return None
        self.contents = r.text
        return self.contents


phelps = OlympicAthlete('michael-phelps')
phelps.get_content()
print(phelps.contents)
```

In this case, you'll get the result twice (in case of a successful connection).
I'd suggest a method, that would only get the result and either return it or that'd assign it to the class attribute, not both.

```py
def get_content(self):
        r = requests.get(self.url)
        if r.status_code != 200:
            print(f'Your get request was unsuccessful with a {r.status_code} error code')
            return None
        return r.text
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to create a method with the same name of a property. You have to rename one of them.

```py
import requests

class OlympicAthlete:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.url = f'https://www.olympic.org/{name}'
        self.contents = None

    def method(self):
        r = requests.get(self.url)
        if r.status_code != 200:
            print(f'Your get request was unsuccessful with a {r.status_code} error code')
        else:
            self.contents = r.text


phelps = OlympicAthlete('michael-phelps')
phelps.method()
print(phelps.contents)
```

But if you want to use the decorator...

```py
import requests

class OlympicAthlete:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.url = f'https://www.olympic.org/{name}'

    @property
    def contents(self):
        r = requests.get(self.url)
        if r.status_code != 200:
            print(f'Your get request was unsuccessful with a {r.status_code} error code')
            return None
        return r.text


phelps = OlympicAthlete('michael-phelps')
print(phelps.contents)
```